# Firebase Permission Denied despite of rule

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My database contains a collection named `users`. Each document, user, in this collection contains a field `nickname`. I am trying to get all the users with a certain nickname:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").orderByChild("nickname").equalTo(someNickname)
```

But I keep getting:

```
Listen at /users failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied
```

So I made the collection read-public using a simple rule:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{user} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow create, write, delete: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

But I am still getting the `Permission Denied` message. Any Idea why?

Comment: do you have any other rules? The phrase (this is just for now) isn't valid. Do you have it in the rules too?

Comment: @ChrisPapantonis that is everything. the (this is just for now) thing is only here. probably shouldn't have added it at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have posted **firestore** rules but your code says that your using **firebase realtime**. Either you have edited the wrong rules or you are using the wrong objects/classes in your code.

The following piece of code tries to access **firebase realtime database** not firestore.

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").orderByChild("nickname").equalTo(someNickname);
```

If you are using firestore check the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) on what classes you must use to access firestore.